# Getting the audio-playtime of a folder from the command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, audio, sox

Is there a way/tool for the linux command-line (bash) to get the overall audio playtime of a certain directory?

Something like:

```
playtime --all --recursive /Music/DrumAndBass/
output: 1:35:06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way by using the tool `mp3info` with `awk`.

Unfortunately this is only working for mp3 files.

```
mp3info -p "%m:%s\n" directory/*.mp3 |
awk -F: '{a+=$1*60+$2}END{printf"%d:%02d:%02d",a/3600,a%3600/60,a%3600%60}'
```

or as tiny bash-script

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"

mp3info -p "%m:%s\n" "$dir/*.mp3" |
awk -F: '{a+=$1*60+$2}END{printf"%d:%02d:%02d",a/3600,a%3600/60,a%3600%60}'
```

[thanks to @steve for the `awk`-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477717/240990)

---

**Update:**

`sndfile-info` or `sox` can get the playtime for different file formats like `flac` or `wav`:

```
sndfile-info audio.flac | awk '/^Duration/ { print $3 }'
```

or the `sox` solution:

```
sox -V3 audio.flac -n |& awk '/^Duration/ { print $3;exit }'
```

(the `exit` in the `awk` command limits the output to only print the first match)

Comment: Try [taginfo](http://grecni.com/software/taginfo/): it works with ID2, ID3V2, Ogg and FLAC tags.

Comment: You might want to try `find $dir -name '*.mp3'` if you have deeper subdirectories.

Comment: @NickD was just wondering, taginfo does not seem to be in the Debian repository?

Comment: I don't know...