# Summing minutes and seconds with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I sum timing values with awk?

I got a list like this:

```
5:45
4:28
4:46
5:13
4:58
3:18
4:59
4:55
3:57
2:1
1:30
2:0
5:18
3:45
6:15
```

and would like an output like this:

```
h:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$ awk -F: '{a+=$1*60+$2}END{printf"%d:%02d:%02d",a/3600,a%3600/60,a%3600%60}' file
1:03:08
$
```

- `-F:` - set `:` as field delimiter
- `{a+=$1*60+$2}` - total up the number of seconds, being field 1 * 60 + field 2.
- `END{printf"%d:%02d:%02d"` - at end of file, print the results in a formatted fashion, i.e. leading zeroes on minutes and seconds
- `a/3600,` - hours is seconds divided by 60 divided by 60
- `a%3600/60,` - minutes is remainder of seconds divided by 60 divided by 60, then divided by 60
- `a%3600%60}` - for seconds, take remainder of seconds divided by 60 divided by 60, and then take the remainder of that divided by 60